# How to generate all heading tags in emmet with text?

Tags: html, emmet

I am trying to generate all heading tags from `<h1>` to `<h6>` like this:

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<h3>heading 3</h3>
<h4>heading 4</h4>
<h5>heading 5</h5>
<h6>heading 6</h6>
```

How can I achieve this using emmet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
h${heading $}*6
```

Above will give you all heading tags with normal text.

Answer (score 2):

this is a simple way to do it `h$*6` then insert text for first one then click tab and repeat process you can read more about Emmett short cuts here: https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/